# Insert decimal separator in SQL result

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySql. I need to convert the double 2783571287 result in the decimal '27835712,87'. In my case, I'm using ',' as decimal separator.

I managed to use the cast function, but I can't previously set the two decimal places that make up the end of the value.

Also, I was not able to "cut" the value using the SUBSTRING function as the amount of characters may vary.

Does someone know how I can do it?

Thanks

Comment: hi, welcome to SO.  You need to include your table schema, an example of the data in the table, and the query you're running and its actual result.

Comment: Cast it to a float, divide by 10, then you can cast it to a string and replace . With ,

Comment: Sounds like you simply want to divide your number by 100. Whether dot or comma is just a display thing. You say you are using comma and you want a comma, so you should be fine. (Using floats and doubles in a database is not recommended by the way. Don't use approximate types, when you can use precise types like the decimal type.)

Comment: Though you can divide the number by 100, I tend to think this is a formatting issue. If that's the case this should be solved at the UI level, not the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also, I was not able to "cut" the value using the SUBSTR function as the amount of characters may vary.

If you want to drop the last two characters, use substr() with length() as

```
mysql> select substr(2783571287, 1, length(2783571287) - 2);
+-----------------------------------------------+
| substr(2783571287, 1, length(2783571287) - 2) |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| 27835712                                      |
+-----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can also extract the last two characters by using right()

```
mysql> select right(2783571287, 2);
+----------------------+
| right(2783571287, 2) |
+----------------------+
| 87                   |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then

```
mysql> select concat(substr(2783571287, 1, length(2783571287) - 2), ',', right(2783571287, 2));
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| concat(substr(2783571287, 1, length(2783571287) - 2), ',', right(2783571287, 2)) |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 27835712,87                                                                      |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I've edited the answer and describe how to concatenate the integer part and the decimal part with a comma, too.

Comment: Thanks guys! I used the following sintax:

*CAST(mycol / 100 AS DECIMAL(20,2))*